# Laravel Cashier charge method fails with 3d secure on single charge

Tags: php, laravel

I need help with Laravel Cashier.

I'm using laravel cashier on backend and vue on client side.

On client I setup stripe object, elements and card.
In the meanwhile I request to serve a client_secret making a PaymentIntent

```
$payment_intent = PaymentIntent::create(
        ['amount' => $request["price"],
            'currency' => "eur",
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'customer' => $stripe_customer->id,
    ], [
        'api_key' => config('services.stripe.secret'),
    ]);
```

When user input credit card data and confirm using the client_secret
I call this function in client side

```
this.stripe.confirmCardPayment(this.stripe_payment_intent.client_secret, {
    payment_method: {
      card: this.stripe_card,
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Test Name'
      }
    },
    setup_future_usage: 'off_session'
  })
  ...
```

On then I call the server passing the result.
On the server side

```
$stripeCharge = $request->user()->charge(
        $request["paymentIntent"]["amount"], $request["paymentIntent"]["payment_method"]
    );
```

It works fine, withouth sca (3d secure)

But when the test card require 3d secure (4000002500003155 or 4000002760003184) on the client all goes fine, displaying the 3d secure
dialog, the confirmCardPayment succeed, but in last step when calling charge I got

The payment attempt failed because additional action is required before it can be completed.

Why? All the actions is performed on the client side.. why the server not agree?

p.s. I need only single charge without store any payment method

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that confirmCardPayment already charge the user.
So calling again in the server side make the error because double charge on 3d secure card is not possible.

I had to remove charge on the server side and using PaymentIntent::retrieve in order to verify the status and check if already processed in my business logic.